# Discord.py send members a direct message after certain time

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to send all server members after 1 week without "extra" roles a direct message with a reminder to pick extra roles on my server. **Is this possible?**

I already searched for a tutorial, but I can't find a way to do this.

Maybe the "extra"-roles can be a role-id list or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

For long periods of time, you probably want to use some sort of persistent data store to keep track of things, but you could reasonably do this in-memory as long as your bot never goes down (or if you're okay with the consequences of a reset)

One key mechanism to use for this is [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/). You can schedule a task to run periodically that will keep track of folks without an 'extra' role.

Keep in mind that tasks scheduling should be less than one day's time. So, in this case, we run the task every ~3 hours, but the task will only send the message every 7 days.

A sketch of this idea for a single guild might look something like this:

```py
# the names of the roles to look for. You could also get these some other way.
EXTRA_ROLE_NAMES = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'} 

import discord
from discord.ext import tasks


class MyBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._next_message_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # send reminder right away when the bot starts
        self.without_extra_role = set()  # set of members without an 'extra' role
        self._message_interval = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        # if you don't want to send the message right away when the bot starts:
        # self._next_message_time = self._next_message_time + self._message_interval
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    @staticmethod
    def has_extra_role(member: discord.Member):
        for role in member.roles:
            if role.name in EXTRA_ROLE_NAMES:
                return True
        return False
    
    async def send_reminder(self, member):
        msg = "Don't forget to pick a role!"
        await member.send(msg)
    
    @tasks.loop(minutes=180)  # run this every 3 hours
    async def check_roles(self):
        guild = ... # get the discord guild object here
        # remove members that have picked a role
        to_remove = []
        for member in self.without_extra_role:
            if self.has_extra_role(member):
                to_remove.append(member)
        for member in to_remove:
            self.without_extra_role.remove(member)

        # Find members who still need to pick a role
        async for member in guild.fetch_members():
            if not self.has_extra_role(member):
                self.without_extra_role.add(member)

        # if it's time to send messages to everyone without a role...
        if datetime.datetime.now() >= self._next_message_time:
            # reset the next time to send the message
            self._next_message_time = datetime.datetime.now() + self._message_interval
            # send the messages
            for member in self.without_extra_role:
                # schedule reminder to be sent in the event loop
                self.loop.create_task(self.send_reminder(member))
```

Here, `self._next_message_time` keeps track of when you should send the next reminder. Ideally, this should be persisted somehow to avoid inconsistencies if your bot goes down.

The `self.without_extra_role` set keeps track of members who have not picked an extra role. Every 3 hours this list is updated (according to the tasks schedule). After 7 days passes, the next time the task runs, it will update the members list and send a reminder to those who are still in the list.

Comment: Does this timer reset when the bot restarts? The timer must "stay" at the right time, not count again if the bot restarts because the bot does this many times.

And i only want to send the reminder 1x time not every 1 week.

Comment: As stated, in which case, you must store that information in a persistent way, like in a file or in a database.

Comment: How can i make this? Sorry, i'm a noob in python.

Comment: Really, this sounds like a separate question. Consider researching how to read/write to files in Python.